# How to delete an Array with negative integers

Tags: c++, pointers

I was trying to solve the following problem,

> Given an array of integers, every element appears three times except
>   for one. Find that single one.

When the input are all positive, I will not get any errors, but when the input contains negative integers, the line `delete index;` will give error, does anybody know why?

i.e.

`A[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,3,4}` works fine, but `A[] = {-2,-2,1,1,-3,1,-3,-3,-4,-2}` does not.

The code is as follow,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class Solution {
public:
    int singleNumber(int A[], int n) {
        // IMPORTANT: Please reset any member data you declared, as
        // the same Solution instance will be reused for each test case.

        int *index;
        std::map<int, int> m;

        index = new signed int[(n+1)/3];
        int flag = 0;
        int result;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(m.find(A[i]) == m.end()) {
                m[A[i]] = 1;
                index[flag] = A[i];
                flag++;
            } else {
                m[A[i]] = m[A[i]] + 1;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<(n+1)/3; i++) {
            if(m[index[i]] != 3) {
                result = index[i];
            }
        }

        delete index;

        return result;
    }
};

int main()
{
   Solution s;

   int A[] = {1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,3,4};
   int result = s.singleNumber(A, 11);
   std::cout <<result;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `delete [] index`, not `delete index`.  Don't know if this will solve your problem, but you need to match array new with array delete.

Comment: What is the error?  You didn't tell us the error message you are getting.

Comment: Why do you even have the `int[]` array? The `map<int,int>` is all you need to solve the problem.

Comment: Always write error message you write about in question

Comment: @zoska How should I get the error message? I am new to C++, I can only find the "Call Stack".

Comment: just explain what `give error` means.

Comment: @zoska if it was in Java, I know how to give you the exception name, but I don't know how to find it in C++.

Comment: So what did you mean by `will give error`. You wrote it yourself. Can you explain it?

Comment: @zoska the program just won't run, it gives the line where it breaks

Comment: For future reference - you need to exactly specify the error - what does it mean it won't run? Does it crash? How does it give the line where it breaks? Is there any message? Saying `give error` is as helpful as saying nothing at all. Just remember that when asking questions in future. That's all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first array contains 11 elements, which causes the line `index = new signed int[(n+1)/3];` to allocate an array of (11+1)/3 = 4 elements. The second array contains 10 elements, which causes that line to allocate an array of (10+1)/3 = 3 elements.

3 elements is insufficient to record the unique values in `A` (-4, -3, -2, and 1), so you overflow the array.

You should allocate at least `(n+2)/3` elements. It would also be prudent to test the value of `flag` to ensure it never exceeds the array bounds. It will not if the input array obeys the constraint that every element but one appears three times (presuming this means it will appear one or two times, not four or more), but can you rely on that constraint being obeyed?

Additionally, the loop `for(int i=0; i<(n+2)/3; i++)` is insufficient to iterate through all the elements that were added to the map. You should be sure you iterate through all the members of `m`.

---

Incidentally, `singleNumber` can be implemented in a much more fun way without any dynamic allocation or library calls:

```
int singleNumber(int A[], int n) {
    int b = 0, c = 0;
    while (n--)
    {
        b ^= A[n] & c;
        c ^= A[n] & ~b;
    }
    return c;
}
```

However, this is completely not what your instructor is expecting.

Comment: You're right, but why A[]={1} gives error at line `delete index;` too?

Comment: @UnkDrew: That case has the same problem: `(n+1)/3` evaluates to `2/3` and then to `0`, so you request zero elements, but you need an element to hold the 1.

Comment: My bad, I didn't mention that I have change it to `(n+2)/3`, It just still won't work.

Comment: @UnkDrew: “Won’t work” is not a sufficient description of what is wrong. You must state exactly what the observed behavior is. A crash? Incorrect output?

Comment: @UnkDrew: I have added a paragraph about another failure, in the loop that finds the odd element. I also added a completely different solution, which you should absolutely not use for this homework assignment.